# adaptive filtering of Recursive least mean square

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am working with the pusleMeter project to measure the pulse signals.

So,I am using the adaptive filtering of Recursive least mean square for removing the noise(motion artifacts similar to motion artifacts present in the ECG signals) from the pulse signals and I modifed the RLMS code from [RLS](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36858-recursive-least-squares-filter)

1)As there is only one noisy pulse signal so there is no reference for the first time so tried to use the lowpass filter version of the first pulse signal(of 500 samples) as the reference for RLS filter

2)After the first pulsessignal(for next 500 samples) it takes the RLSfitler output as the reference signal.

I implemented like this

```
 clear all;
 clc;
 P=load('Noise_Pulse_signal.mat');
a2=P.a1;
for i=1:500:length(a2)
    if(i<499)
 For the first pulse signal(500samples) the reference signal is approximated as the LPfilter version of the first pulse signal.
     x1=a2(i:i+499,:);
        d = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',2.4,8,1,40,500);
        Hd1 = design(d);
        LP = filtfilt(Hd1.Numerator,1,x1);
          plot(LP,'-r');
        pause(0.2);
        e=LP';
      else
         x=e;
        x1=a2(i:i+499,:); 
        x1=x1';
        [e,w] = RLS_1(x,x1,500);
        pause(0.2);
    end;
end
```

RLS_1 function as this

```
function [e,w] = RLS_1(n,x,fs)
  % Filter Parameters
  p       = 4;                % filter order
  lambda  = 1.0;              % forgetting factor
  laminv  = 1/lambda;
  delta   = 1.0;              % initialization parameter
  % Filter Initialization
  w       = zeros(p,1);       % filter coefficients
  P       = delta*eye(p);     % inverse correlation matrix
  %e       = x*0;              error signal I'm not using this as the LPfilter output will be used as the e(reference signal).
    for m = p:length(x)    
      y = n(m:-1:m-p+1);% Acquire chunk of data
      e(m) = x(m)-w'*y;% Error signal equation
      Pi = P*y;% Parameters for efficiency
      k = (Pi)/(lambda+y'*Pi);% Filter gain vector update  
      P = (P - k*y'*P)*laminv; % Inverse correlation matrix update   
      w = w + k*e(m);% Filter coefficients adaption   
  end
  toc
    t = linspace(0,length(x)/fs,length(x));
  figure;
  plot(t,x,t,e);
  title('Result of RLS Filter')
  xlabel('Time (s)');
  legend('Reference', 'Filtered', 'Location', 'NorthEast');
  title('Comparison of Filtered Signal to Reference Input');
  return
```

But it is giving error like this

```
        Error in RLS_1 (line 15)
     e(m) = x(m)-w'*y;% Error signal equation
         Error in Motion (line 18)
       [e,w] = RLS_1(x,x1,500);
```

Can anyone please explain me why the error is being generated and if this the correct way of implementation for the above mentioned requirement as I need a efficient method so that it can be implemented on the micrcontroller. 
 Thankyou.

Comment: what is your error message? make sure your dimensions of e, x, and y are consistent.